# facebook comments glued up together

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I am using facebook comments for my website and have used the below code

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="www.siteURL.com/articleID" data-width="478" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

The comments should get pasted based on articleID and should be displayed for the same articleId but instead, all the comments are glued up together and coming up for all the articles. Can you please let me know where is the bug and how can I resolve it ?

Comment: Do you use Open Graph meta tags on your website? If you do, is the value of the `og:url` the same as the URL you have in the `data-href` attribute?

Comment: No, we are not using Open graph meta tag.